# Помощь со скриптом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Помогите чтоб при клике на Открыть текст менялся на Cвернуть

https://jsfiddle.net/kcvhoaj7/

```
$('.btn_toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".list-items__lvl2").slideToggle(400, function() { 
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("opened")) 
      $(this).parent().removeClass("opened");
    else $(this).parent().addClass("opened");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.btn_toggle').click(function() {
  var $lvl2 = $(this).closest(".list-items__single").find(".list-items__lvl2");
  $lvl2.slideToggle(400, function() { 
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("opened"); 

    var $btn = $(this).parent().find(".btn_toggle");
    $btn.text($(this).parent().hasClass("opened")? "Cвернуть" : "Открыть");
  });
});
```

Comment: что-то вы отредактировали и перестало работать) в предыдущем варианте было все ок

Comment: @websterjoy https://jsfiddle.net/kcvhoaj7/16/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn_toggle').click(function() {

  if($(this).html() == "Открыть")
    $(this).html("Скрыть");
  else
    $(this).html("Открыть");

  $(this).parent().parent().find(".list-items__lvl2").slideToggle(400, function() { 
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("opened")) 
      $(this).parent().removeClass("opened");
    else $(this).parent().addClass("opened");
  });
});
```

Может и некрасиво, зато работает)))